# Microsoft Graph API 500 Internal Server Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently using the Microsoft Graph API v1.0 and it has been working fine until this morning where we started receiving 500 internal server errors. I cannot figure out what the source of the issue is. Has anyone ever ran into this error? Or can someone point me in the right direction of how to resolve this?

Using this GET endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/` returns 500 Internal Server Error response. Currently the only header I'm using is 'Authorization = Bearer {{accessToken}}'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.AgsIndexConfigProvider.GetConfigVersionNumber(String configType, String configId) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\AgsIndexConfigProvider.cs:64
   Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.ConfigurationProvider`1.GetConfigurationImp(String identifier, Boolean useCache) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\ConfigurationProvider.cs:418
   Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.ConfigurationProvider`1.GetConfiguration(String identifier, Boolean useCache) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\ConfigurationProvider.cs:108
   Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.GlobalContext.TryGetConfigurationItem(String identifier, TConfigItem&amp; item) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\GlobalContext.cs:324
   Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.GlobalContext.GetAgsRootConfig() in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\GlobalContext.cs:276
   Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.ThrottleClient.GetThrottleEndpoint() in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Throttling\ThrottleClient.cs:576
   Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.ThrottleClient.Initialize() in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Throttling\ThrottleClient.cs:129
   Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.WebService.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\WebService\Global.asax.cs:128

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +531
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +166
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +165
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +368
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +329

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +118
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +704
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[NullReferenceException]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.AgsIndexConfigProvider.GetConfigVersionNumber(String configType, String configId) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\AgsIndexConfigProvider.cs:line 64
   at Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.ConfigurationProvider`1.GetConfigurationImp(String identifier, Boolean useCache) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\ConfigurationProvider.cs:line 418
   at Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.ConfigurationProvider`1.GetConfiguration(String identifier, Boolean useCache) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\ConfigurationProvider.cs:line 108
   at Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.GlobalContext.TryGetConfigurationItem[TConfigItem](String identifier, TConfigItem& item) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\GlobalContext.cs:line 324
   at Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.Gateway.GlobalContext.GetAgsRootConfig() in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Gateway\GlobalContext.cs:line 276
   at Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.ThrottleClient.GetThrottleEndpoint() in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Throttling\ThrottleClient.cs:line 576
   at Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.Common.ThrottleClient.Initialize() in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\Common\Throttling\ThrottleClient.cs:line 129
   at Microsoft.Online.AggregatorService.WebService.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in X:\bt\941900\repo\src\dev\WebService\Global.asax.cs:line 128
[HttpException]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
[HttpException]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
--><!-- 
This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using &lt;customErrors mode="Off"/&gt;. Consider using &lt;customErrors mode="On"/&gt; or &lt;customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/&gt; in production environments.-->
```

Comment: you should contact microsoft for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like their graph API is down.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Thanks for the response! It appears that is the case. I was hoping this would be visible to Microsoft Support since they point to Stack Overflow for questions. Will look into opening an issue on GitHub

Comment: I'm now seeing that it is back up.